# retain count for mutable and immutable object in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, retaincount

```
NSArray *arr=[[NSArray alloc]init]; //Am getting all immutable objects allocation that retain count:2  
NSLog(@"dic1:%d",[arr retainCount]); 
[arr retain];
[arr retain];
[arr retain];
[arr release];
 NSLog(@"dic2:%d",[arr retainCount]);


NSMutableDictionary *dic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];//Am getting all mutable objects allocation that retain count:1  
NSLog(@"dic3:%d",[dic retainCount]);
[dic retain];
[dic retain];
[dic retain];
[dic release];
NSLog(@"dic4:%d",[dic retainCount]);
```

OUTPUT :dic1:2
 dic2:4
 dic3:1
 dic4:3

what is the diff between mutable objects retain count and immutable objects retain count?pls give me solution...

Comment: retainCount is useless. Don't bother with it.

Answer (score 6):

If you add the following line

```
NSLog(@"%p %p %p", [NSArray new], [NSArray new], [NSArray new]);
```

then you will notice that all pointer values are the same (and also that initial value of dic1 went up by three and now starts with 5). Which means that `[[NSArray alloc] init]` does not actually allocate anything, but just retains some always-alive singleton and returns it.

**Never** rely on value of `retainCount`, because the object may be internally retained by runtime and frameworks. Some objects may not even have retain counter. This also implies that you shouldn't expect that `release` will predictably cause deallocation.

Comment: You sir, have enlightened me. Didn't know it would cache arrays like that.

Answer (score 0):

Never use the `retainCount` method, because it never gives the real values, because the inner implementation of the object may contain `retain`s, so you will have your `retain`s and the system's `retain`s.